# What is the difference in these code fragements?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can anyone tell me what is the major difference between these two codes?

code 1:

```
       Fragment fragment = new NaviagtionFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.pager, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

code 2:

```
NavigationFragment fragment = new NavigationFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.pager, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

Comment: @Raghunandan now see,i updated those questions

Comment: What's your actual problem with your code?

Comment: @fasteque i just want to know how my code works? there is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both options instantiate a `NavigationFragment` and replace it for the one inside `pager`. So there's no difference at all during runtime.

The only difference is regarding methods/instance variables visibility at compile time.

Declaring

```
Fragment fragment
```

you won't see custom methods/instance variables of `NavigationFragment`. However, if you're not doing anything else with `fragment`, the first option is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case you are assigning the object to the base class, in the second to the derived class. The mainly difference is that you can not access the derived methods and properties in the first case but only the one from the base type (without a cast)